# Failed to execute goal on project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz:performance-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gatling

I am trying to execute one of the Jenkins job which has Java main class with maven. I am executing mvn clean package just to get jar. Then,

```
exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.XYZ.MainHandler"
```

But this gives me following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project performance-test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.XYZ:performance-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at io.gatling:gatling-core:jar:2.2.5 -> io.advantageous.boon:boon-json:jar:0.6.6 -> io.advantageous.boon:boon-reflekt:jar:0.6.6 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2.redhat-2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2.redhat-2: Failure to find org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:pom:1.7.2.redhat-2 in https://xyzaf.com/artifactory/libs-release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of libs-release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: Delete directory  `{homeDir}/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api`. Try again. Does it help?

Comment: Try to use `mvn -U` ... to force update.

Comment: both options are not working